# How does Python interpreter implement coroutine

Tags: python, yield, coroutine

Currently, I'm trying to understand how Python implements `yield` and generators. On the documentation it says

> By suspended, we mean that all local state is retained, including the current bindings of local variables, the instruction pointer, the internal evaluation stack, and the state of any exception handling. When the execution is resumed by calling one of the generator’s methods, the function can proceed exactly as if the yield expression were just another external call.

This seems extremely counterintuitive to me as all the function calling schemes I know are stack based such as C calling convention. I'm really curious how Python stores all the states of a function under the hood and how the flow of execution gets back to the place after the `yield`.

And one last question is that is there any algorithm to derive the implementation of a generator iterator from an arbitrary generator function. For example, assume we have a generator function:

```py
def generator_f():
    for i in range(10):
        yield i
    for i in range(10):
        yield i
```

Could we systematically implement an iterator that's functionally equivalent to the generator iterator returned by `generator_f()`? Functionally I mean both behavior and (memory) efficiency.

Comment: Python (the language) does not implement this nor defines how exactly it has to be implemented. The interpreters are free to find their own solution. So, I guess you are talking about CPython (the mostly used Python interpreter)?

Comment: I'm fine with any possible implementation, but I guess CPython will be better as for its popularity.

Comment: In general, coroutines are "just" a syntactic sugar for [finite-state machines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite-state_machine). You could write a class, move all of the local variables into instance variables, and have one enum that tracks which yield you're currently "sitting at." The rest is just code transformation.

Comment: I guess that's one way to look at it. Also shouldn't that be more like a (simulated) Turing Machine as you need a place to store some extra states?

Answer (score 0):

You can see how Cpython implements coroutines here in [`cpython/Lib/asyncio/coroutines.py`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/asyncio/coroutines.py). To see how generators are implemented see [`cpython/Objects/genobject.c`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/d4f9cf5545d6d8844e0726552ef2e366f5cc3abd/Objects/genobject.c). Specifically, the logic behind `yield from` is found in the functions `gen_getyieldfrom()` and `_PyGen_yf()`.

Regarding your question about an equivalent iterator:

```
iter([*range(10), *range(10)])
```